# React component content disappears after page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and am having trouble figuring out why the data inside my Content component does not re-render on refresh.

When I visit one of the routes, say `/sentences-of-the-day`, and then I refresh the page, it seems all the stuff inside content is gone.

Can someone please help me out?

Here is the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mainichome-v7hrq

Comment: I've tried to reproduce what you are seeing, but I couldn't. It works fine for me. Stupid question, have you tried a different browser or clearing your cache?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind that react only re renders a component when the state changes. You set the state once on the component load the initial load. But you never reset the state afterwards. React works in the virtual Dom, so once the component loads that's what's rendered until the state changes. What's happening is there is now a new filter keyword but, since these keywords presumably don't match anything else in your data that was initially passed, there's nothing to render

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to post an external link with details of the question, since these links can and do change over time, reducing the value of your question and the answers to it. Adding code inline in the question is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `data` once the component is mounted (using `useEffect`) set to local `state` to trigger the `render`. In each refresh, mounting happens again and you have the data after each refresh.

Define another function in `content.data.js`

```
export const getContentData = () => {
  return Promise.all(contentDataStories.map((func) => func()));
};
```

In your `content.component.jsx`

```
  import { getContentData } from "./content.data.js";

  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setContent(await getContentData());
    })();
  }, []);
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/mainichome-forked-4sx5n?file=/src/components/content/content.component.jsx:302-449

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
import contentData from "./content.data.js";

//...

const [content] = useState(contentData);
```

That imports `contentData` and then sets it as state.

However, that value is asynchronous.

```
const contentData = [];

contentDataStories.forEach(function (func) {
  func().then((json) => {
    contentData.push(json);
  });
});

export default contentData;
```

It's just `[]` until those promises reoslve.

So what's happening is that the page is loading fine, but the content from that file hasn't loaded before the first render.

This is a race condition. Which will happen first, the data loading or the render? Sometimes the render wins and everything is fine, but sometimes it doesn't and you get a blank page.

---

To fix it, you need to make React aware of your data loading, so that it can re-render when the data finishes loading.

First make a function that does your async loading:

```
export function getContentData() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // fetch async stuff here
    resolve(myDataHere)
  })
}
```

And then call that from a `useEffect`, which sets the state.

```
function Content() {
  const { titleParam } = useParams();
  const [content, setContent] = useState(contentData);

  useEffect(() => {
    getContentData().then(setContent);
  }, [getContentData]);

  //...
}
```

Now when you component mounts, it calls `getContentData`. And then that promise resolves, it sets the state, triggering a a new render.

Comment: thanks for explaining this core concept.  Learning something new